# ggplot2 - How do get bins of two different histograms to match?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following histogram which uses the default binwidth,

```
x <- rnorm(100)
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=x))
```

I want the following histogram to have the exact same bins as `p1`,

```
x <- rnorm(100)/2
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=x))
```

In other words, I want `p2` to use the same default bins as `p1`. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `geom_histogram(..., binwidth=???)`?

Comment: If you want the data to use the same distribution use `set.seed(???)` before the `rnorm()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that we can do is to extract breaks from the first plot:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100)
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x1))

breaks <- unique(unlist(ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]][, c("xmin", 'xmax')]))

x2 <- rnorm(100) / 2
p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x2), breaks = breaks)

library(gridExtra)    
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to force the same bins is to facet the plots (because just setting `binwidth` might start bins at different places on two different plots, and manually setting limits with `boundary` and `breaks` will need to be done for the particular data which could be annoying). Plus, this makes the plots directly comparable on their axes as well as the bins, which is presumably the point of putting them on the same bins in the first place

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100) / 2
)
tbl %>%
  gather(var, val, x, y) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = val)) +
  facet_wrap(~var)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).